# HttpServletRequest#getRemoteAddr() returns NULL

Tags: java, servlets

Why does [`HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) return `null` *sometimes*? For approximately 2 out of 10 identical requests is returns `null` for no apparent reason.

Comment: Read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262887/why-httpservletrequest-getremoteaddr-doesnt-work-in-java-servlet

Comment: @AVD Returning NULL is not mentioned there.

Comment: I am having the same problem running JBoss AS 7.1. My server receives approx 9000 requests ~= 9GB of text in a short timespawn every day. During load testing, some hits to my webservice come up with a null on getRemoteAddr().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Tomcat7. Apparently `getRemoteAddr()` can return `NULL` if the request has already been consumed, i.e. a response has been sent. It can even throw NPE sometimes. An error in my code in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Did you pass the request object to another thread to read it asynchronously? In some web container, request objects will be recycled/reset once the servlet thread is finished. Then you might get `null` when `request.getRemoteAddr()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

That would be either a bug or a misconfiguration in the specific servletcontainer or proxy used. Lookup which one you are using, check its version and check if this bug has been reported before to its maintainers and check if there is a newer version to which you can upgrade.