# HttpServletRequest#getHeader("User-Agent") returns null browser name

Tags: java, servlets, browser-detection

I'm using Java 6. I have very less knowledge of JSP and Servlets.

I'm using the following code to get browser name in which my application is running:

```
String browserName = requestProvider.get().getHeader("User-Agent");
```

Also I'm using the following code to get IP address of the machine on which my application is running:

```
String ipAdd = requestProvider.get().getRemoteAddr();
```

In both the cases `requestProvider` is a reference variable of type `Provider<HttpServletRequest>`. And I'm assured that it is never `NULL`.

Now the problem is some times I get both values (`browserName and ipAdd`) NULL.
I've written sometimes because I don't have a test case.

So my question is, what are the cases in Java, when these values can be NULL?

What care should I take in coding to avoid this issue?

Is there any alternate way to get IP address & browser name every time?

Comment: some clients/browsers might not send User-Agent header .  Try with `user-agent` .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Can you give me the exact code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser/18030465#18030465

Comment: You can't trust a single byte that comes into your application in the request.  Therefore you can't trust anything to be not-null.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> String browserName = requestProvider.get().getHeader("User-Agent");

`null` means whoever sent the request didn't include a ["User-Agent" header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43).

> String ipAdd = requestProvider.get().getRemoteAddr();

is unlikely to return null under normal circumstances, but there are reports that it may do so in edge cases, like [after the response has already been sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938221/httpservletrequestgetremoteaddr-returns-null). Regardless, "get IP address of the machine on which my application is running" doesn't sound like what `getRemoteAddr()` is for. It's for getting the address of the most recent client or proxy that sent the request.

> Is there any alternate way to get IP address & browser name every time?

No. You're entirely dependent on the behavior of the HTTP client and/or any intervening proxies to get information like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using user-agent as lowercase, because it works if we directly access from header.

String browserName = requestProvider.get().getHeader("user-agent");

alternate way to get IP address is

String ip = requestProvider.get().getHeader("True-Client-IP"); this works if we have akamai integeration.

Comment: header names are not case sensitive